# howto remove udev from centos(lxc-guest) without dependencies

Tags: yum, centos6, init.d, udev, lxc

i downloaded a openvz template for my lxc server to create a new centos 6.3 guest. 
Now the guest is not starting because udev is hanging in the boot process. 
Last time i didn't had this problem but now i have to disable or remove udev from the guest.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to confirm which udev version you have installed. run this command
**rpm -q udev** 
If you have udev installed then this will show you the name and version of rpm.
then you want to remove udev without removing dependencies
for this run this command
rpm -e your udev rpm name --nodeps
for example  rpm -e udev-095-14.24.el5 --nodeps

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this issue

excluding udev* in yum.conf for example just causes a ball ache with future upgrades etc.

I'd suggest commenting "/sbin/start_udev" out of

> /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit

..for good measure I also blank the bastard out (I so very passionately hate udev):

> cp /dev/null /sbin/start_udev